# How does one get the dimensions of an image from a stream (without rendering it)?

Tags: bitmap, dimensions, windows-phone-7, cameracapturetask

I'm doing the standard CameraChooserTask dance.  In my callback, I'd like to get the dimensions of the captured photo.

I tried using `BitmapImage`, as below, but since the `BitmapImage` isn't part of the render tree, I don't think it actually does any decoding (its `ImageOpened` event doesn't fire).

```
private void CameraCapture_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
  if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK && e.ChosenPhoto != null)
  {
    // This code DOES NOT work:
    // BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    // bi.SetSource(stream);
    // ... use bi.PixelHeight and bi.PixelWidth ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, the trick is to force someone to use the `BitmapSource`.  By assigning it as the source for an `Image`, the `PixelHeight` and `PixelWidth` properties get set.

```
private void CameraCapture_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
  if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK && e.ChosenPhoto != null)
  {
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.SetSource(stream);

    Image image = new Image();
    image.Source = bi;

    // ... use bi.PixelHeight and bi.PixelWidth ...
```